# Android Studio Not Installing on OSX PC

Tags: android-studio

I have been waiting for over 2 hours for Android Studio to be reinstalled on a mac. I have attempted to reinstall this application more than 20 times now for the last week, and the application just hangs every time. I even let it sit for a whole day but still nothing. I'm not getting any error message. I checked the activity monitor and it isn't frozen.

After following the instructions from the [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html), it gets stuck for hours with no end in sight. I have included an image below of where it gets stuck (basically right at the beginning) I have restarted the computer several times to see if that would help and Android Studio shows up as an available application but when I try to use it, I get the same screen.

[image]

Details:

- Mac: OS X El Capitan version 10.11.4
- Java version: 1.8.8_91
- JAVA_HOME location: Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
- Before every reinstallation, I used App Cleaner to ensure all Android Studio files were deleted.

Does anyone have a clue what the issue is or might be? Any suggestions? I have searched on Google for answers and have yet to find anyone experiencing anything like this.

---

**[UPDATE]**

As I'm unfamiliar with Mac OS X, I finally decided it best to use the studio executable file (Android Studio > Show Package Contents > MacOS > studio). From there, the terminal shows with so many errors. I have included the information below. Hopefully this is enough information to help. Thanks.

```
2016-05-13 09:26:45.696 studio[3925:111495] Value of STUDIO_JDK: (null)
2016-05-13 09:26:45.700 studio[3925:111502] fullFileName is: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2016-05-13 09:26:45.700 studio[3925:111502] fullFileName exists: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2016-05-13 09:26:45.700 studio[3925:111502] Value of STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2016-05-13 09:26:45.700 studio[3925:111502] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2016-05-13 09:26:45.700 studio[3925:111502] Done
2016-05-13 09:26:45.700 studio[3925:111502] Processing VMOptions file at /Users/username/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.1/studio.vmoptions
2016-05-13 09:26:45.700 studio[3925:111502] No content found
2016-05-13 09:26:45.700 studio[3925:111502] Processing VMOptions file at 
2016-05-13 09:26:45.700 studio[3925:111502] No content found
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties: 'java.endorsed.dirs' already defined
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@29acfd6 for /com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib
Found library resource at jar:file:/Applications/Android%20Studio.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib
Trying /Users/username/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio2.1/tmp/jna-1197065905/jna203230282572986310.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /Users/username/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio2.1/tmp/jna-1197065905/jna203230282572986310.tmp
Looking for library 'c'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying libc.dylib
Found library 'c' at libc.dylib
Looking for library 'Foundation'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying libFoundation.dylib
Adding system paths: [/usr/lib, /usr/lib]
Trying libFoundation.dylib
Looking for matching frameworks
Trying /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
Found library 'Foundation' at /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
[   4897]   WARN - oidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider - File /Users/username/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
[   5573]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found 
[   5617]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Missing file '/Users/username/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_23_x86.avd/config.ini'. 
[   5618]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - java.lang.NullPointerException 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:204)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:361)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.AndroidVirtualDevice.isSelectedByDefault(AndroidVirtualDevice.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallableComponent.updateState(InstallableComponent.java:124)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.ComponentCategory.updateState(ComponentCategory.java:70)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:243)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:94)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:95)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame.<init>(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.createFrame(FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.java:29)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:169)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:340)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:200)
    ... 16 more
[   5620]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 2.1.1  Build #AI-143.2821654 
[   5620]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.7.0_79 
[   5620]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[   5620]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[   5620]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
[   5620]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching everywhere for an answer (others have had [similar issues](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72248) but it doesn't seem like there has been a real fix), I only had one solution which was to install an [older version](http://tools.android.com/download/studio) of Android Studio. I installed the stable 1.5.1 version and was FINALLY able to get Android Studio running to start a new project. From there, I upgraded to version 2.1.1 from the same site and it worked.

Steps to Resolve:

1. download older, stable version of Android Studio
2. Upgrade to latest, stable version to address security issues

Thanks for the help. If anyone actually has a fix instead of a workaround, feel free to add a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open file located at "/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
Change the content to

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Xmx : specifies the maximum memory allocation pool for a Java Virtual Machine (JVM).
Xms : specifies the initial memory allocation pool.

The JVM starts with Xms amount of memory and should be able to use a maximum of Xmx amount of memory.

Save studio.vmoptions file and restart Android Studio.

Comment: I edited the document as recommended and I received a popup stating " 'Android Studio' is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash." This recommendation unfortunately didn't work for me.